# Proof inside a proof

Tags: bussproofs

I want to put a proof inside a proof using `bussproofs`. The following code produces exactly what I want.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\newcommand{\VDots}{\vphantom{\int^0}\smash[t]{\vdots}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\hspace{17mm}
$\left(
        \AxiomC{$(A)$}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$\VDots$}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$B$}
    \DisplayProof
\right)$
\end{center}
\vspace{-2mm}
\begin{center}
        \AxiomC{$A\to B$}
        \AxiomC{\mbox{}}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$\VDots$}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$C$}
        \BinaryInfC{$C$}
    \DisplayProof
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

But obviously that's not ideal. What I *want* is to be able to take this chunk of code:

```
$\left(
        \AxiomC{$(A)$}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$\VDots$}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$B$}
    \DisplayProof
\right)$
```

And shove it into where I currently have a `\mbox{}` in the second proof. But that gets me an error.

Comment: Would you be interested in a solution using an alternative package (`mathpartir`)?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I didn't make that explicit in my question. i suppose a bussproofs solution would be preferred, since I already know the syntax, but if you know of a way easier way to do things, I'd be happy to hear of it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that busproofs does not support nesting of proofs. However, you can save the inner proof into a box and then use the box inside the outer proof.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\newcommand{\VDots}{\vphantom{\int^0}\smash[t]{\vdots}}
\begin{document}

\newsavebox\InnerProof
\sbox\InnerProof{$\left(
        \AxiomC{$(A)$}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$\VDots$}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$B$}
    \DisplayProof
\right)$%
}

\begin{center}
        \AxiomC{$A\to B$}
        \AxiomC{\usebox\InnerProof}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$\VDots$}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$C$}
        \BinaryInfC{$C$}
    \DisplayProof
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, and not at all odious! I'll wait a few days to encourage other answers, but this is really quite good.

Comment: @Shay My answers are never odious ;-) Using an sbox is a general trick (maybe already a method) to reduce interference between some inner and outer typesetting.

Comment: @gernot Can we use the same approach to have nesting of tikzmatrices (or are there any hidden issues) ? (I have heard using positioning and fit libraries is better; still I would like multiple ways)

Comment: @CyriacAntony No idea, try it ...